# Cannot connect .xib file after corresponding classes are already created

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

I'm using xCode 4.2, and after creating the .h and .m classes separately, I go and add a .xib file of the same name. So now I have:

```
ExampleClass.h
ExampleClass.m
ExampleClass.xib
```

However, the ExampleClass.xib won't connect to ANYTHING. I try dragging it to file's owner, to anything, and it won't connect. How do I go about doing this? The differences I see are that when creating all of them at the same time (.h, .m, and .xib), I see that when clicking on file's owner, it has "searchDisplayController" and "view" in the Outlets under the Connections Inspector. The one I created after the fact, ExampleClass.xib, has no "Outlets" section. I may be overlooking something, but I've tried restarting xCode, looking at other example code, etc... and I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Interface Builder, show the utilities, beyond that show the show the identity inspector and assign the custom class.

Answer (score 4):

The first connection is in the Identity Inspector, which you can quickly access by pressing Option+Command+3. You must also set the File's Owner's view Property to the main view in the nib. The second step is often overlooked, and that results in a seemingly inexplicable crash.